# I want to change my corporate developer thinking mindset and want to learn Linear Algebra, Statistics and Calculus for improvement

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, career-development

Hello Math Stackexchangers, I am a typical corporate developer who is bored by doing repetitive work, I need change and I am ready for it. I want to learn Linear Algebra, Statistics and Calculus, help me build my learning path or recommend me some good beginner level book. I can spend up to 8-10 hours per day for learning.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what type of job you'd like to switch into?

Comment: Schaumn's series with summary of key facts, solved examples and supplementary exercises.

Comment: @TannerSwett for now i have no plans for switching carrier, just want to learn , it will boost my thinking capability.

Comment: Have you considered studying at a distance university? It may help to study with some guidance, being able to connect with other students/professors, and maybe even get a university degree out of it! 8-10 hours per day for learning is a lot!

Comment: Thank you @johnnycrab for suggestion, i have not considered distance university courses. I spend max  1-2 hours per day to complete my work . suddenly realised i m just wasting my time and taken things for granted. for now i have started Gilbert Strang mit opencourseware but found its not for beginner level

Comment: Thanks @GNUSupporter for edits, does Schaumn's series books are for beginner level. cross checked review on amazon for Schaum's Outline of Linear Algebra 5th Edition got negative 1 star reviews                                              http://www.amazon.in/Schaums-Outline-Linear-Algebra-5th/dp/0071794565/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1487326986&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Schaumn%27s+series+algebra+5th+edition

Comment: It's a collection of books on different topics. I like it for revision, especially for more abstract topics like general topology, differential geometry, etc.  I found that it's for people with almost any background like me.  Anyone can name some linear algebra books written by great authors like Gilbert Strang, Serge Lang, etc.  Have a try and you'll know what's the best for you.

Comment: If you are going to study statistics before calculus, I suggest one of the books by D.S.Moore such as _Basic Practice of Statistics._ The edition doesn't matter; maybe you can get a used copy of an older edition inexpensively. These books are widely used in the US by high school students getting college credit for a beginning statistics course. They do not pay much attention to probability, but you can look into probability-based statistics after calculus.

Comment: I agree that Moore's book *Basic Practice of Statistics* is a well written introductory book. For linear algebra, I'm a fan of Gilbert Strang's books such as *Introduction to Linear Algebra*. Video lectures are available on the MIT Open Courseware website. Strang also has a calculus book which I haven't read, but which I think is probably good.